# Finding the points of discontinuity. Different answers if I simplify the algebraic function?

Tags: calculus

Find the points of discontinuity of the following function:
\begin{align}
 f(x) = (x^2 - 4) / (x^2-2x)
\end{align}

By simplifying it, I get:
\begin{align}
 f(x) = (x-2)(x+2)/x(x-2)
\end{align}
And again:
\begin{align}
 f(x) = (x+2)/x
\end{align}

Obviously, one of the points of discontinuity is x=0. 
But is x=2 a point of discontinuity as well? 
If I understand well, to find a point of discontinuity is to find the value of x in which the denominator will be equal to 0.
Thank for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly, for your function $f$, the value $x=0$ is the location of a non-removable discontinuity, i.e., an asymptote. This would not be a point of discontinuity.

The value $x=2$ is the location of a removable discontinuity, that is, a point of discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot simplify first. By doing so you get rid of the possibility of having $\frac 00$.

This "undefined" ratio corresponds to a hole on the graph of the function. So the function looks "almost" continuous at $x=2$.

We call this type of singularity a **removable singularity**, since we could redefine our function so that it is continuous at $x=2$, simply by "filling-in the hole".

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-2x}=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x(x-2)}=\frac{x+2}{x}$$ only if $x\ne 2$ we have a new definition of $f(x)$ namely
$$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{x}$$ if $x\ne 2$ and $$f(x)=2$$ if $$x=2$$